# way to get ephemeral port from php?

Tags: php, http

I know this is an unconventional question, but I'm looking for ways to cut corners with multiple systems.
Is there any way in PHP to determine the ephemeral port of the connection being used in the HTTP request?
I'd like to log that value and pass it into a DB for use by another application.

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) might be there.

Comment: Did you try `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']`?

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need. If one of you puts it in an answer, I'll accept it asap.